# How to compile AppleScript for application that is not installed

Tags: macos, email, outlook, applescript, osx-mountain-lion

I have a script, which creates a new email message with default mail client on mac. The script contains a code, that relates to Microsoft Outlook if it finds that it was set as the default Mail application. The problem is that on macs, that Outlook wasn't installed this script even doesn't pass a compilation, because probably Apple Script cannot find Microsoft Outlook dictionary. What is the proper way to handle this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you might handle it.

NOTE: in order for the script to not need compilation you must 1) save the script as an application. Applications do not need to compile on another machine. And 2) you use the "using terms from" claus in your script.

I added the do shell script stuff so you can check for Outlook prior to running the outlook code if you need it. I hope that helps.

```
set outlookExists to false
try
    do shell script "osascript -e 'exists application \"Microsoft Outlook\"'"
    set outlookExists to true
end try

if outlookExists then
    using terms from application "Microsoft Outlook"
        tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
            -- do something
        end tell
    end using terms from
else
    -- do something else

end if
```